# Preventing input function from generating files not present in sample file

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I've been working on a snakemake problem I've been unable to solve. Given a file of samples such as:

```
tissue type replicate file
ear rep1 H3K4me3 00.data/chip_seq/H3K4me3/ear_H3K4me3_rep1.fastq
ear rep2 H3K4me3 00.data/chip_seq/H3K4me3/ear_H3K4me3_rep2.fastq
ear rep1 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/ear_input_rep1.fastq
ear rep2 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/ear_input_rep2.fastq
leaf rep1 H3K4me3 00.data/chip_seq/H3K4me3/ear_H3K4me3_rep1.fastq
leaf rep2 H3K4me3 00.data/chip_seq/H3K4me3/ear_H3K4me3_rep2.fastq
leaf rep1 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/ear_input_rep1.fastq
leaf rep2 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/ear_input_rep2.fastq
root rep1 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/ear_input_rep1.fastq
root rep2 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/ear_input_rep2.fastq
```

The snakemake function I utilize to input this list of files - here called `get_chip_mods` generates combinations of wildcards that do not actually exist. So in this case `get_chip_mods` generates combinations such as `root_rep1_H3K4me3` even though said file is not specified in the samples. Is there a way to prevent this function from generating combinations that are not present within the samples file?

Below is the beginning of my pipeline.

```py
#Load Samples from the CSV file - index the important ones
samples = pd.read_csv(config["samples"], sep=' ').set_index(["tissue", "type", "replicate"], drop=False)
samples.index = samples.index.set_levels([i.astype(str) for i in samples.index.levels])  # enforce str in index



rule all:
    input:
    ¦   "00.data/reference/bowtie_idx.1.bt2",
    ¦   expand("00.data/trimmed_chip/{tissue}_{chip}_{replicate}_trimmed.fq" , tissue = samples["tissue"], 
chip = samples["type"], replicate = samples["replicate"]),


#This is where I believe I've been hitting issues. 
def get_chip_mods(wildcards):
    final_list = samples.loc[(wildcards.tissue, wildcards.type, wildcards.replicate), ["file"]].dropna()
    print(final_list)
    return final_list


rule trim_reads:
    input:
    ¦   get_chip_mods
    params:
    ¦   "00.data/trimmed_chip/log_files/{tissue}_{type}_{replicate}.log"
    output:
    ¦   "00.data/trimmed_chip/{tissue}_{type}_{replicate}_trimmed.fq"
    threads: 5
    message:"""Trimming"""
    shell:
    ¦   """
    ¦   java -jar /usr/local/apps/eb/Trimmomatic/0.36-Java-1.8.0_144/trimmomatic-0.36.jar \
    ¦   SE -threads {threads} -phred33 {input} {output} \
    ¦   ILLUMINACLIP:/scratch/jpm73279/04.lncRNA/02.Analysis/23.generate_all_metaplots/00.data/adapter.fa:2:30:10 \
    ¦   LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36
    ¦   """
```

The error I receive is as follows

```
KeyError: 
Wildcards:
tissue=root
type=H3K4me3
replicate=rep1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has to do with the `expand` function in the rule `all`. The function will by default will use the python itertools `product` to generate all possible combinations of your wildcards. Some of these combinations do not exist in your dataframe index and thus the error.

`expand` however allows you to customize the way in which the wildcards are combined and thus you can rewrite the function in the following manner to resolve the issue.

```py
expand("00.data/trimmed_chip/{tissue}_{chip}_{replicate}_trimmed.fq".split(), zip, tissue = samples["tissue"], chip = samples["type"], replicate = samples["replicate"])
```

[Source](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets)

Answer (score 0):

The only key for solving your ambiguity is the file with the possible combinations. That means that your script shall be written in a way that doesn't depend on which combinations are possible.

One way to solve that is to replace your three wildcards in the `all` rule with a single wildcard `{tissue_type_replicate}` and produce the possible values using a python function. That would give Snakemake the information of which files it needs to produce. You can make the same change in other rules too (that is the simplest and workable solution as long as you don't need exact values of `{tissue}` `{type}` and `{replicate}` in the `shell` section). Anyway you still may leave the `{tissue}` `{type}` and `{replicate}` wildcards untouched in other rules: Snakemake should find the match.